# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

in my site, i am using the value stored in cookie to be displayed once the site is opened, so for that whenever the site is opened iam replacing window.location with the url stored in cookie. But initially it shows an uncaught error, but when i refresh the site the error is gone and it redirects to the url in cookie. This is my code:

```
                var url=$.cookie("lastUrl");//getting url from cookie

               window.location.replace(url);//replacing it to window.location
```

This is the error iam getting:

```
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #page2?aid=322952&artistId=322952&id=334945`
```

This is where cookie is set:

```
    var lastUrl= window.location.hash;

    $.cookie("lastUrl", lastUrl);
```

What have i done wrong in this????

Comment: What's the line where you set the cookie?

Comment: can you log the value of url to console and see if it has any quotes or any bad character which needs to be escaped ?

Comment: This is the console of the url http://localhost:8890/example/index.html#page2?aid=318892&artistId=318892&id=328469

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var url = $.cookie("lastUrl"); //getting url from cookie
>
> window.location.replace(url); //replacing it to window.location
> ```

the `replace` method of location requires a URL, your are giving it just the hash.

Comment: i replaced the code and set url in cookie instead of hash .                        var last url=window.location.href.                                                                  Then also getting the same result.